# Dot Product for dummies with CUDA C

Tags: c, cuda, dot-product

I'm trying do a simple tutorial about dot product in cuda c using shared memory; the code is quite simple and it basically does the product between the elements of two arrays and then sums the result of from each block:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>

#define imin(a,b) (a<b?a:b)

const int N = 33*1024;
const int threadsPerBlock = 256;
const int blocksPerGrid = imin(32 , (N+threadsPerBlock-1)/threadsPerBlock);

__global__ void dot(float *a, float *b, float *c){

__shared__ float cache[threadsPerBlock];
int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x; 
int cacheIndex = threadIdx.x; 
float temp = 0; 
while (tid < N){
    temp += a[tid]*b[tid];
    tid += blockDim.x*gridDim.x; /* Aggiorno l'indice per l'evenutale overshoot. */
}
cache[cacheIndex] = temp; 
__syncthreads(); 

int i = blockDim.x/2; 
while(i != 0){ /
    if(cacheIndex < i){ 
        cache[cacheIndex] += cache[cacheIndex + i];
        __syncthreads(); 
        i /= 2; 
    }      
}
if(cacheIndex == 0){ 
    c[blockIdx.x] = cache[0]; 
}
}

int main(void){

cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess; 

float a[N], b[N], c[blocksPerGrid];
float *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;   
int i;
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    a[i] = i;
    b[i] = i*2;  
}
for(i=0; i<blocksPerGrid;i++){
    c[i] = 0;
}

err = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, N*sizeof(float));
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector a (error code %s)! \n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
err = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_b, N*sizeof(float));
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector b (error code %s)! \n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
err = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_c, blocksPerGrid*sizeof(float));
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector c (error code %s)! \n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
/* Copio i valori dei vettori a e b nello spazio di memoria allocato precedentemente nel device. */
err = cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector a from host to device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
err = cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector b from host to device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
err = cudaMemcpy(d_c, c, blocksPerGrid*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector c from host to device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}


dot<<<blocksPerGrid,threadsPerBlock>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c); err = cudaGetLastError();

err = cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, blocksPerGrid*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector c from device to host (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

err = cudaFree(d_a); 
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free device vector a (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
err = cudaFree(d_b); 
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free device vector b (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
err = cudaFree(d_c); 
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free device vector c (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}


float result = 0;
for(i=0;i<blocksPerGrid;i++){
    result += c[i];
}

printf("il risultato finale è: %.2f\n", result);

return 0;
}
```

This code is identical to the one presented in the Cuda by Example book where the only difference is in the definition of the vectors a, b and c (the way i defined them shouldn't be a problem since I've done it several times).

Here's the problem: when i try to run the program it crashes! The terminal says that the problem is: `Failed to copy vector c from device to host (error code the launch timed out and was terminated)!`

That seams strange since i think i have allocated vector c in the proper way... does anyone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong? is it the global function or the main that has something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your kernel has an infinite loop in it.  The reason you are getting an error at all is because you are on a platform that has a watchdog timeout, and the watchdog is killing the kernel execution.

consider this code:

```
int i = blockDim.x/2; 
while(i != 0){
    if(cacheIndex < i){ 
        cache[cacheIndex] += cache[cacheIndex + i];
        __syncthreads(); 
        i /= 2; 
    }      
}
```

You are only dividing the loop index (`i`) by 2 if the `cacheIndex` is less than `i`.  For other threads, `i` remains at the same value constantly, once that thread drops out of the if statement.  For those threads, the while loop is never exited (`i` is never equal to zero).  You want to divide the `i` variable for all threads.  Like so:

```
int i = blockDim.x/2; 
while(i != 0){
    if(cacheIndex < i){ 
        cache[cacheIndex] += cache[cacheIndex + i];
    }   
    __syncthreads(); 
    i /= 2;    
}
```

Note that I have moved the `__syncthreads()` out of the if statement as well.  This may not be necessary to fix your issue, but is technically not correct because we generally want all threads to participate in a `__syncthreads()` statement.  It is only allowed in conditional code if the condition evaluates the same across all threads -- this is [documented in the programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions).

And if you compare your code in this respect to what is in the [cuda by examples source code for dot.cu in chapter 5](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/books/cuda-by-example/cuda_by_example.zip), I think you'll find they are *not* identical.

Comment: Now that i read it I understand what you mean... and it works (thank you very much)!!! but i also tried to leave the __syncthreads(); between the brackets and it still works.. is it just a case?

Comment: I don't know what just a case means.  It happens to work.  It is officially undefined behavior.  You should avoid it.

Comment: sorry i meant if it's a coincidence ahah... ok i'll remember that!